# how to make a inline button generator with sqllite in aiogram 3.0

Tags: python, aiogram

I need to make a button generator using a database, here is an example on aiogram 2.0, how to do it on aiogram 3.0

```
def genmarkup(data):

builder = KeyboardBuilder(button_type=InlineKeyboardButton)
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=builder.export())


for i in data: 
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(i[1], callback_data=i[2]))
return markup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `InlineKeyboardMarkup` and `InlineKeyboardButton` classes:

```py
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, KeyboardBuilder

def genmarkup(data):
    builder = KeyboardBuilder()
    for i in data:
        button = InlineKeyboardButton(text=i[1], callback_data=i[2])
        builder.add(button)
    return builder.as_markup()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Please see updated code